# Ubuntu 20.04 – Cant wake from sleep unless HDMI cable is unplugged and reconnected

Tags: suspend, screen

I have a laptop that is connected to an external monitor and I would like the lid to remain closed. This works but, when I try to wake the computer from sleep using an external keyboard, the machine will not resume. If I unplug the HDMI cable and plug it back in, then the screen turns on and I can use the computer again.

I tried the solutions [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167424/external-monitor-not-detected-by-ubuntu-19-04-after-sleep), but I cannot find an "Enable module video-out" option in my user interface.

Here is some information about my computer:

[image: System – About]

How can I solve this problem?

edit: I tried running the command :  laptop-mode-tools .

[laptop-mode-tools-not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfvc6.jpg)

Comment: Did you install the `laptop-mode-tools` package as the answer suggested? What options do you see in the UI? 

Comment: ye I tried what you said but I get the messge that the comand not found .

Comment: It apparently does not install such a command line utility. Instead, it adds a dialog to the graphical system menu. I am using KDE, pressed the Windows key to get the menu, typed "laptop" into the search bar, and found the "Laptop Mode Tools Configuration" dialog.