# Ports on a Thunderbolt 3 dock are missing after unplugging/reconnecting, or suspend/resume

Tags: 20.04, thinkpad, thunderbolt

I'm having an annoying problem with a Thinkpad X1 running Ubuntu 20.04, and a Thunderbolt dock.

The dock works fine after the laptop boots. All ports, Ethernet and USB work fine.

All ports disappear after either:

1. Disconnecting or reconnecting the laptop from the dock.
2. Keeping the laptop connected to the dock, then suspending and resuming it.

The laptop still gets power from the dock, and responds to the on/off button from the dock, from this point on, so it's still communicating with it. But all the ports are gone. In all other respects the laptop functions normally.

After a random interval of time, anywhere between a few minutes to several hours, the ports come back by themselves, and work fine.

An immediate reboot also re-enables all ports as well.

I tried unplugging the laptop from the dock, resuming, then reattaching it to the dock. This made no difference. The laptop takes power from the dock, responds to the on/off button on the dock, but does not see any ports on it.

Comment: No permanent solution. I only found that generating constant network traffic usually causes the ports to come up after a few minutes. I start Google Meet, with only myself in it, and let the camera stream my video into the void. Within seconds, or a few minutes, the ports come back up.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problems with external monitor connected over USB-C to my Dell Latitude 5501. After hunting a solution for a months, I have finally found something working.
By forcing linux to rescan PCI devices, the monitor comes back and xrandr finally sees it:

```
echo "1" | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/rescan > /dev/null
```

More info:
https://superuser.com/a/1046942

Optionally, you can install laptop-mode-tools, which are most probably using the same approach, but on my system it is sometimes causing the CPU to never go below maximum frequency:
[External monitor not detected by Ubuntu 19.04 after sleep](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167424/external-monitor-not-detected-by-ubuntu-19-04-after-sleep)

Comment: The OP says the dock is the issue so not sure how this helps.

Comment: I believe the root cause is the same, that some of the PCI devices (in my case the monitor) is not visible by system. Forcing linux to rescan the PCI devices should fix the not working ports on the dock.